# Infinite render cycle on redirect inside for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have a page in my project where I have several tabs. My application has multiple user roles and their permissions to view the tabs vary.
For instance, the default tab is called "General" in case the user opens this page and does not have permissions to view the "General" tab the following code redirects the user to the 1st tab that he's allowed to view.

```
for (let i = 0; i < permissions.length; ++i) {
   if (user.Permission.indexOf(permissions[i].code) >= 0) {
     history.push(`${permissions[i].path}${id}`);

     break;
   }
}
```

The problem is that this code goes into infinite render cycle but if I remove `break` statement it seems to be working fine. I'm just wondering why does it behave like that?

Comment: Not sure; anyway, to prevent the infinite loop, make sure the path pushed to history isn't the current path.

Comment: Do you have the specific permission you are looking for? The loop within the loop is unnecessary IMO, you should be checking for a specific permission, not doing a brute force check.

Comment: No, I just want to redirect to the 1st one that is allowed for the user. Let's say 1st (default) and 2nd are not allowed, I want to redirect straight to the 3rd

Comment: Ok, I understand. Are you perhaps missing a '/' in `${permissions[i].path}${id}`? Like `${permissions[i].path}/${id}`. I'm assuming if it cannot find the path, it is going to revert to the default path which is going to keep you in the infinite loop.

Comment: The `path` string has '/' at the end. Like I said it's working if I remove the `break` statement, so I'm just curious what's the logic behind it. It would be nice to know what exactly happens when you redirect from within the `for` loop and what difference does it make if you include or exclude `break`